# How to copy a formatted Excel table into Gmail? (with simple solution)

Tags: microsoft-excel, gmail

A simple copy paste of table from Microsoft Excel in Gmail email removes all table formatting. Like most I was also looking at solutions and tried different things (like pasting table first in Word, Google Sheet, etc. and then copying from there and pasting in Gmail email).

A simple solution to above problem is to use "Format as Table" option in Microsoft Excel. Make further necessary changes in formatting as required and then copy the table and paste it in the Gmail email body. Done!

Comment: The embedded answer (shouldn't do that) does not work for me. Gmail pastes either a bitmap image of the table or unformatted plain text.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to above problem is to use "Format as Table" option in Microsoft Excel. Make further necessary changes in formatting as required and then copy the table and paste it in the Gmail email body. Done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells to be copied and click Format as Table in the Home tab.
[image]